# Is there a way to stop Form from executing action and wait for ajax to complete executing?

Tags: javascript

Before customers can proceed to paypal, I have a quick check on the database to see if the items still available,. The problem im having is that while Ajax is executing. function **check_availability** continue executing and returns true to the Form onsubmit before the completion of Ajax. To fix that problem I kept calling the same function within. But I dont think that is the best possible option.

Here is the code:

```
<form  onsubmit="return check_availability(0,0,1)"  action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" id="pp1">

function ajax_paypal(orders){
    var htpr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "Hi there";
    var val = "orders="+orders;
    htpr.open("POST", url, true);
    htpr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    htpr.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(htpr.readyState == 4 && htpr.status == 200){
            var sold_out_ids = htpr.responseText;
            check_availability("continue", sold_out_ids, 0);
        }
    };
    htpr.send(val);
}

function check_availability(str, sold_out_ids, n) {
    if (str === "continue") {
        if (sold_out_ids > 0) {
            alert("One of your items has sold out! Sorry for any inconvenience");
            location.reload();
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }else if(n === 1){
        var orders = [];
        var x = document.cookie.split(';'); // your array of cookies
        var i = 0;
        x.forEach(item => {
            //to make sure that item contains "order"
            if (item.indexOf('order') > -1) {
                var val = item.split("=");
                orders[i] = val[1]+"o";
                i++;

            }
        });
        ajax_paypal(orders);
    }
    check_availability(0, 0, 0);//I keep calling this until Ajax is completed
}
```

Comment: You can try preventing submission of form on submit using `event.preventDefault()`, and on ajax success you can go for `window.location.href = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr"`

Comment: @divy would all the POST infor still be send to paypal if I do this method?

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code snippet to solve. This will be called on submit but before actual submit happen if you return true from here form will get submit to paypal. If you return false form won't get submit.

```
  $('#pp1').submit(function() {
    var submitOrNot=await callcheck_availability();

    return true; // return false to cancel form submit
});

async function callcheck_availability(){
//your function goes here
}
```

for more on async await read this page on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

Comment: wont this always return true, as while Ajax is executing, this function will carry on executing too leading to always return true?